# Concat DataFrame of uneven lenght

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

i want to concat two DataFrame horizontally (axis=1), each containing different information on a game. In `player_df`, i have the individual data of the player for the game (one row per player/ match), in `match_df` i have the general match data (one row per match). For each match there is 10 player so `player_df` should be 10 times greater then `match_df` if there weren't any errors. Both df are indexed by match_id.

I would like to concatenate the two DataFrames into one (lets call it `main_df`), repeating all `match_df` observation ten times so that each row of `main_df` contains individual features as well as match feature, keeping it indexed by `match_id`.

Would any of you be kind enough to point me in the right direction?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In order to help you please provide a reproducible example. What do the dataframes look like, what have you tried? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You might wanna look into joins in a dataframe...

Comment: Please post your sample data set and expected results as mentioned by ScootCork. Otherwise your chances of getting the answer is less.